# Pri slave drive ATAPI incompatible after setting bios to ACHI for ssd

Tags: optical-drive, atapi

The title says it all. I installed a SSD C:\ drive, and also have a SATA CD/DVD drive. When booting, the POST screen says that the CD/DVD Drive is ATAPI incompatible. In windows the CD/DVD works fine, but when I want to use a live DVD ie: Knoppix, it won't boot because of the  incompatibility.

I have the following hardware:

- Biostar i55, (SATA 2) motherboard
- sata CD/DVD drive
- SSD crucial 300c as pri hard drive for windows

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little odd to answer my own question, but the problem was that IDE was still active in the bios. After disabling the drive in the bios, the cd/dvd drive worked great!

Comment: It's not at all odd to answer your own question! Just make sure you mark it as "Accepted" by clicking the green checkmark beside this answer so others can find the solution.